# Android: Published App crashes with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android-activity, classnotfoundexception

I have just published my first app today but for some reason when I use the published version I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException error when it starts up. It works fine when I test it in debug mode on my phone so I'm not sure whats causing this.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.androidProjects.personal/com.androidProjects.personal.GAAClubFinderActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.androidProjects.personal.GAAClubFinderActivity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.androidProjects.personal.GAAClubFinderActivity
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
    ... 11 more
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Just an update on this. I did a clean on the project, re-signed the apk file and uploaded it again. Its working now. I'm not entirely sure what the problem could have been but at least its sorted.